# error: CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Tasks'

Tags: swift, core-data

My app is working fine, but when I open the app I get warnings in console from CoreData

Error:

> [error] error: CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Tasks'
> CoreData: error: CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Tasks'

the class of CoreData:

```
class CoreDataManager {
let persistentContainer : NSPersistentContainer

init() {
    persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TodoList")
    persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores { description, Err in
        if let err = Err {
            fatalError("Core Data Store failed \(err.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
func updateData() {
        
        do {
            try persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            persistentContainer.viewContext.rollback()
        }
        
    }
func deleteData(message: Tasks) {
        
        persistentContainer.viewContext.delete(message)
        
        do {
            try persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            persistentContainer.viewContext.rollback()
            print("Failed to save context \(error)")
        }
        
    }
func getAllData() -> [Tasks] {
       
       let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Tasks> = Tasks.fetchRequest()
       
       do {
           return try persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
       } catch {
           return []
       }
       
   }

func SaveData(Title: String , text: String , date:String , isComplete:Bool)  {
    let Tasks = Tasks(context: persistentContainer.viewContext)
    Tasks.date = date
    Tasks.isComplete = isComplete
    Tasks.title = Title
    Tasks.text = text
    
           do {
               try persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
            
           } catch {
               print("Failed to save movie \(error)")
            
           }
}
```

}

my Model:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lM2Vj.png)

Comment: (Maybe) unrelated but it’s pretty bad practice to name a variable with the same name as the class. Use always names with starting lowercase letter to avoid confusion. It seems that you create somewhere a new task with `Tasks()`.

Comment: @vadian I try Change the names , but same the problem!

Comment: Changing the name isn't the important thing, look in your code and see if you call `Tasks()` somewhere

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I try Change the names , but same the problem!

Comment: That is not what I wrote. Read the second part of my comment.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I found var in contentView "@"State var Dataa : Tasks = Tasks()

Comment: Good, that means you found the cause of the error. Either change to `Tasks(context:)` or refactor your code in some other way, the important thing is to remove `Tasks()`. Since you have your SaveData function you probably don’t need that property  at all.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson ok what add in `Tasks(context:)`?

Comment: viewContext from PersistenceContainer but like I said, you don’t need that property

Comment: @JoakimDanielson same problem `@State var Dataa : Tasks = Tasks(context: CoreDataFunctions.persistentContainer.viewContext)`

Comment: Well now you know what to look for.